# Creating settings for scripts

Tags: python

Im using a code in which a settings.py file needs to be created with my required parameters.

Ive created a Gui which would generate this file and run the script that needs this file, then after the script has finished, I delete the settings.py and the subsequently generated settings.pyc. When I try to run it again, the settings dont update to the new ones in the settings.py file, it uses the old ones. This is solved when I close and reopen my Gui, what can I do so that it will take the new settings?

Comment: try `importlib.reload`

Comment: ah forgot to say im using python 2.7, i dont think that exists in 2.7

Comment: Well then look up whatever the equivalent thing was. Note, you *really* should be using Python 3, Python 2 is passed it's official end of life.